# How does a trained SVR model predict values?

Tags: svm, predict

I've been trying to understand how does a model trained with support vector machines for regression predict values. I have trained a model with the `sklearn.svm.SVR`, and now I'm wondering how to "manually" predict the outcome of an input.
Some background - the model is trained with kernel SVR, with RBF function and uses the dual formulation. So now I have arrays of the dual coefficients, the indexes of the support vectors, and the support vectors themselves.
I found the function which is used to fit the hyperplane but I've been unsuccessful in applying that to "manually" predict outcomes without the function `.predict`.
The few things I tried all include the dot products of the input (features) array, and all the support vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever needs this, I've managed to understand the equation and code it in python.
The following is the used equation for the dual formulation:

[image: equation 1]

where **N** is the number of observations, and **α<sub>i</sub>** multiplied by **y<sub>i</sub>** are the **dual coefficients** found from the model's attributed `model.dual_coef_`. The **x<sub>i</sub><sup>T</sup>** are some of the observations used for training (support vectors) accessed by the attribute `model.support_vectors_` (transposed to allow multiplication of the two matrices), **x** is the input vector containing a value for each feature (its the one observation for which we want to get prediction), and **b** is the intercept accessed by `model.intercept_`.
The **x<sub>i</sub><sup>T</sup>** and **x**, however, are the observations transformed in a higher-dimensional space, as explained by [mery in this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265656/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-important-features-weight-for-an-svm-that-uses).
The calculation of the transformation by RBF can be either applied manually step by stem or by using the `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel`.
With the latter, the code would look like this (my case shows I have 589 support vectors, and 40 features).
First we access the coefficients and vectors:

```
 support_vectors = model.support_vectors_
 dual_coefs = model.dual_coef_[0]
```

Then:

```
pred = (np.matmul(dual_coefs.reshape(1,589), 
                  rbf_kernel(support_vectors.reshape(589,40),
                             Y=input_array.reshape(1,40), 
                             gamma=model.get_params()['gamma']
                             )
                 )
        + model.intercept_
       )
```

If the RBF funcion needs to be applied manually, step by step, then:

```
vrbf = support_vectors.reshape(589,40) - input_array.reshape(1,40)
pred = (np.matmul(dual_coefs.reshape(1,589), 
                  np.diag(np.exp(-model.get_params()['gamma'] * 
                                 np.matmul(vrbf, vrbf.T)
                                )
                         ).reshape(589,1)
                 )
        + model.intercept_
       )
```

I placed the `.reshape()` function even where it is not necessary, just to emphasize the shapes for the matrix operations.
These both give the same results as `model.predict(input_array)`