# How to predict from trained kernlab SVR model in R?

Tags: r, svm, r-caret, predict, kernlab

I have a trained SVR model using the caret package in R. I trained the model for numerical prediction. I used the RBF kernel. I can get the coefficients, support vectors, and parameters from the trained model.

```
uptakemodel <- train(uptake ~ ., data = training, method = 'svmRadial', trControl = ctrl, tuneLength = 10)
uptakemodel

svp <- uptakemodel$finalModel

xmat <- svp@xmatrix
coeffs <- svp@coef
b <- svp@b
sigma <- svp@kernelf@kpar$sigma
```

How can I use these parameters and coefficients to predict new values, rather than using the `predict()` function?

I see an answer from a [Python SVR model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385861/how-does-a-trained-svr-model-predict-values?rq=2), and have tried the same method in R, but I am not getting the same answer as when using the `predict()` function.